# The LINQ expression could not be translated. Translation of method 'System.Nullable<bool>.GetValueOrDefault' failed

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I understand this is because my query won't translate down to SQL, but I'm not sure at which point in the query it's tripping up..

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(t => __oteUids_0 .Contains(t.Oteuid) &&
> t.Active.GetValueOrDefault())' could not be translated. Additional
> information: Translation of method
> 'System.Nullable.GetValueOrDefault' failed. If this method can
> be mapped to your custom function, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```cs
var intakeIds = db.TblIntakeOte
    .Where(iOte => oteUids.Contains(iOte.Oteuid) && iOte.Active.GetValueOrDefault())
    .Select(iOte => iOte.IntakeId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
    
return $",{string.Join(",", intakeIds)}";
```

Comment: Have you tried `iOte.Active == true`?

Comment: The message is pretty self-explanatory: Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate `Nullable<>.GetValueOrDefault()` to SQL.

Comment: What's interesting is that this *used* to work. Back in 2018 [they added](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10153) a [GetValueOrDefault translator](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/4cd4301c27ace85d24ef95dbb7eeee28d27b58d2/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/GetValueOrDefaultTranslator.cs). However they've since modified that to *only* handle [**numeric** nullables](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/06b2b1f75fbfd16501d2b6bfec6d0374cf203b03/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Internal/GetValueOrDefaultTranslator.cs#L43). I can't find the PR for that side of it

Answer (score 2):

As suggested 'iOte.Active == true' fixed the issue

Comment: It seems odd that a flag like .Active would be a Null-able Boolean rather than just a Boolean, but when dealing with Null-able values it is generally better to emphasise that fact in the code using either `&& (iOte.Active ?? false)` or `&& (iOte.Active.HasValue && iOte.Active.Value)` if you want a #null Active flag to be treated as False.

Comment: If you keep as non-nullable in the model and then try to add a Sql-level default value to it, specifically one that is `false`, EF raises warnings. This is because EF then can't determine if a `false` value meant `false` or meant it wasn't provided. There's scenarios where you might want different things to happen if the user doesn't supply a value versus one that's explicitly false. It's a bit annoying and I'm dealing with the same in my project (though our column is the inverse-- an IsInactive false)